# Horizontal transparency gradient

Tags: adobe-photoshop

In Photoshop, how can I create a horizontal gradient of transparency?

For example, I would like a grey background with a 100% opacity band in the center and opacity progressively reaching 0% at the left and right edges.

Similar to https://www.shutterstock.com/fr/image-illustration/modern-abstract-horizontal-background-white-transparent-1113297590, though with transparency inverted.

Comment: Welcome to **GD.SE** - please take a peek around [tour] to learn a bit about our community, and look over [ask] and [answer] a question to learn what make a good query here and how to frame it for best responses. Can you tell us what you've tried so far, and where you're struggling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the gradient editor to change the opacity of the stops.

To bring up the gradient editor, click on the gradient tool, then click on the gradient in the tool options along the top.

[image]

When the gradient editor opens, then set up three colour stops of 50% grey (the stops below the gardient), and add three opacity stops (the stops above the gradient), then select the opacity stop at each end as shown below, and set the opacity of each to 0%.

[image]